# Sinon not stubbing due to multiple test cases

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/akl47/sinontest)

When I run my test cases using mocha, sinon will set up the stubs based on the first app.js that gets called. Looking at other people having the same problems it looks like the problem is that when I `require('../../../app')` it is pulling in a cached version so it is using the same stubs as whatever was set up the first time I called it.

What I've tries in the beforeEach section on both test cases:

- `decache('../../../app'); app = require('../../../app')`
- Using Sinon Sandbox and restoring
  that
- `delete require.cache[require.resolve('../../../app')]; app = require('../../../app')`
- Using mockery to reset the cache

I dont know if its calling the cached version of the requirement or if I'm not stubbing it out correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

By default, modules are imported in a Singleton-type behaviour in Node e.g.

```
const app = require('./app');
app.someProperty = 'x';
```

If I `require` app again in another file *after* this, then you can expect `someProperty` to still be `x` because, as you have worked out, Node will cache the result and return the same one every-time.

In your case this is less an issue with Node, and more your usage of Sinon - when you `stub` something, the common practise is to restore the value back after the test is finished e.g.

```
const app = require('...');

before(() => sinon.stub(app,'someFunction'));

after(() => app.someFunction.restore());
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to stub out middleware which is not a function of the app. So I can not stub out the app like that.

Comment: @akl47 please provide a short but complete example of the code that doesn't work and explain how you expect it to work.